# How is an old question "modified today"?

Tags: discussion

This old question, with answers, appeared today with the only indication, "modified today", without any link to what has been modified: *[Experiment: pendulum with constant driving force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/332645/experiment-pendulum-with-constant-driving-force)*

How can one see the modification and judge whether to spend time on the new appearance?

Answer (score 7):

You can see the revision history by clicking here:

[image]

This shows you the revision history, which shows all of the changes. In this case, it was bumped automatically, not actually modified:

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

The bot occasionally bumps questions to give them more visibility. You can read more about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/380389).

Comment: In this case, but not if a new answer, say, by a spammer, has already been deleted?

Comment: @PeterMortensen If you have the ability to see deleted answers (at 10k reputation), then an answer will still show up in the revision history even if it has been deleted. Otherwise, you can conclude that it must involve a deleted answer by process of elimination.